GeoTools WFS-ng plugin - WFS GetFeature request fails on parsing response
I'm trying to load data from this online WFS service:
https://inspire.skgeodesy.sk/eskn/rest/services/INSPIREWFS/kn_wfs_inspire/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

I'm using the wfs-ng geotools plugin and i'm having issues trying to query for data using the GetFeature request type.
Here's the code:
    public List<KatastralneUzemieAdminHraniceEntity> administrativneHraniceKatastralneUzemie() throws IOException {
        WFSDataStore dataStore = createWFSDatastoreKatastralneUzemie();
        //ContentFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource(esknEiaProperties.getKatastralneUzemieWFSNazovFeature());

        List<KatastralneUzemieAdminHraniceEntity> katastralneUzemieAdminHraniceEntityList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Define query parameters
        String typeName = "cp:CadastralZoning"; // Feature type name
        Filter filter = Filter.INCLUDE; // Include all features
        String[] propertyNames = null; // Retrieve all properties
        Integer maxFeatures = 1; // Max features to return

        // Create query
        Query query = new Query(typeName, filter, propertyNames);
        query.setMaxFeatures(maxFeatures);

        // Execute query
        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);
        SimpleFeatureCollection features = featureSource.getFeatures(query);

        // Process returned features
        System.out.println("Returned Features:");
        try (SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = features.features()) {
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next();
                System.out.println(feature.getID() + ": " + feature.getProperties());
            }
        }

        // Close the data store
        dataStore.dispose();
        return katastralneUzemieAdminHraniceEntityList;
    }

    private WFSDataStore createWFSDatastoreKatastralneUzemie() throws IOException {
        String wfsUrl = "https://inspire.skgeodesy.sk/eskn/rest/services/INSPIREWFS/kn_wfs_inspire/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?";

        // Create parameters for the WFS DataStore
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.URL.key, wfsUrl);
        params.put(WFSDataStoreFactory.PROTOCOL.key, Boolean.FALSE);


        WFSDataStore dataStore = createDatastorePreKatastralneUzemiaInternal(params);
        return dataStore;
    }

This is akin to calling wfsDataStoreFactory.createDataStore(params) from the plugin. I had to create custom WFSClient otherwise i was not able to recive any data.
    private WFSDataStore createDatastorePreKatastralneUzemiaInternal(final Map<String, ?> params) throws IOException {
        final WFSConfig config = WFSConfig.fromParams(params);

        {
            String user = config.getUser();
            String password = config.getPassword();
            if (((user == null) && (password != null))
                    || ((config.getPassword() == null) && (config.getUser() != null))) {
                throw new IOException(
                        "Cannot define only one of USERNAME or PASSWORD, must define both or neither");
            }
        }

        final URL capabilitiesURL = org.geotools.data.wfs.impl.WFSDataAccessFactory.URL.lookUp(params);

        final HTTPClient http = wfsDataStoreFactory.getHttpClient(params);
        http.setTryGzip(config.isTryGZIP());
        http.setUser(config.getUser());
        http.setPassword(config.getPassword());
        int timeoutMillis = config.getTimeoutMillis();
        http.setConnectTimeout(timeoutMillis / 1000);
        http.setReadTimeout(timeoutMillis / 1000);

        // WFSClient performs version negotiation and selects the correct strategy
        WFSClient wfsClient;
        try {
            wfsClient = new WFSClientCustom(capabilitiesURL, http, config);
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }

        WFSDataStore dataStore = new WFSDataStore(wfsClient);
        // factories
        dataStore.setFilterFactory(CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory(null));
        dataStore.setGeometryFactory(
                new GeometryFactory(PackedCoordinateSequenceFactory.DOUBLE_FACTORY));
        dataStore.setFeatureTypeFactory(new FeatureTypeFactoryImpl());
        dataStore.setFeatureFactory(CommonFactoryFinder.getFeatureFactory(null));
        //dataStore.setDataStoreFactory(wfsDataStoreFactory);
        dataStore.setNamespaceURI(config.getNamespaceOverride());

        return dataStore;
    }

public class WFSClientCustom extends WFSClient {

    public WFSClientCustom(URL capabilitiesURL, HTTPClient httpClient, WFSConfig config) throws IOException, ServiceException {
        super(capabilitiesURL, httpClient, config);
        super.specification = new StrictWFS_2_0_Strategy() {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> buildGetFeatureParametersForGET(GetFeatureRequest query) {
                Map<String, String> kvp = super.buildGetFeatureParametersForGET(query);
                kvp.put("NAMESPACES", "xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)");
                return kvp;
            }
        };
        ((WFSStrategy) specification).setCapabilities(super.capabilities);
    }
}

I had to create custom WFSDataStore with custom WFSClient cause the service would not respond without the "NAMESPACES" parameter in the GetFeature calls with value "xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)")".
Right now the communication with the server works fine but I can't get the internal parser to parse the data from response into SimpleFeatureIterator with this error stack trace:
apr 18, 2024 9:19:00 AM org.geotools.xsd.impl.HTTPURIHandler getConnection
INFO: https://inspire.skgeodesy.sk/eskn/rest/directories/arcgisforinspire/schema/networkservices/inspire_fds/1.0/inspire_dls.xsd
2024-04-18 09:19:03,101 INFO  [main] [---] hsqldb.db.HSQLDB6BD103EBD8.ENGINE invoke0:-2 - dataFileCache open start
Returned Features:
apr 18, 2024 9:19:05 AM org.geotools.xsd.Schemas getImports
INFO: Schema import wasn't resolved: http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/ad/4.0 declared location: ad/4.0/Addresses.xsd
apr 18, 2024 9:19:05 AM org.geotools.xsd.Schemas getImports
INFO: Schema import wasn't resolved: http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/au/4.0 declared location: au/4.0/AdministrativeUnits.xsd
apr 18, 2024 9:19:05 AM org.geotools.xsd.Schemas getImports
INFO: Schema import wasn't resolved: http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0 declared location: cp/4.0/CadastralParcels.xsd
apr 18, 2024 9:19:05 AM org.geotools.xsd.Schemas getImports
INFO: Schema import wasn't resolved: http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/gn/4.0 declared location: gn/4.0/GeographicalNames.xsd
apr 18, 2024 9:19:05 AM org.geotools.xsd.Schemas getImports
INFO: Schema import wasn't resolved: http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/hy/4.0 declared location: hy/4.0/HydroBase.xsd
apr 18, 2024 9:19:05 AM org.geotools.xsd.Schemas getImports
INFO: Schema import wasn't resolved: http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/hy-p/4.0 declared location: hy-p/4.0/HydroPhysicalWaters.xsd
apr 18, 2024 9:19:05 AM org.geotools.xsd.Schemas getImports

java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't parse SimpleFeature of type SimpleFeatureTypeImpl http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0:CadastralZoning identified extends Feature(geometry:geometry,label:label,level:level,nationalCadastalZoningReference:nationalCadastalZoningReference,referencePoint:referencePoint,upperLevelUnit:upperLevelUnit) from xml.
identifier=https://inspire.skgeodesy.sk/eskn/rest/services/INSPIREWFS/kn_wfs_inspire/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&STOREDQUERY_ID=urn:ogc:def:query:OGC-WFS::GetFeatureById&id=cpZoningS.1
level={href=http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/codelist/CadastralZoningLevelValue/1stOrder, title=1stOrder}
levelName=katastrálne územie
label=Stanča
validFrom=2024-04-11T18:00:00
inspireId={versionId=null, namespace=SK.ESKN.CP, localId=873179}
referencePoint=POINT (48.564744882 21.657255808)
endLifespanVersion=null
beginLifespanVersion=null
nationalCadastalZoningReference=873179
upperLevelUnit=null
name={grammaticalGender=null, pronunciation=null, spelling={transliterationScheme=null, text=Stanča, script=null}, sourceOfName=null, grammaticalNumber=null, nameStatus=null, language=null, nativeness=null}
geometry=MULTIPOLYGON (((48.574338585 21.658480965, 48.574338191 21.658512458, 48.574338037  21.655316079, 48.574095809 21.656069217, 48.574328243 21.65784314, 48.574342838 21.658128299, 48.574338585 21.658480965)))
id=cpZoningS.1
originalMapScaleDenominator=null
estimatedAccuracy={null=-1.000000, uom=m}
validTo=null


    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:176)
    at pam.eskn.wfs.WfsEsknClient.administrativneHraniceKatastralneUzemie(WfsEsknClient.java:234)
    at pam.AdminHraniceTest.testWfsKatastralneUzemie(AdminHraniceTest.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't parse SimpleFeature of type SimpleFeatureTypeImpl http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0:CadastralZoning identified extends Feature(geometry:geometry,label:label,level:level,nationalCadastalZoningReference:nationalCadastalZoningReference,referencePoint:referencePoint,upperLevelUnit:upperLevelUnit) from xml.
identifier=https://inspire.skgeodesy.sk/eskn/rest/services/INSPIREWFS/kn_wfs_inspire/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&STOREDQUERY_ID=urn:ogc:def:query:OGC-WFS::GetFeatureById&id=cpZoningS.1
level={href=http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/codelist/CadastralZoningLevelValue/1stOrder, title=1stOrder}
levelName=katastrálne územie
label=Stanča
validFrom=2024-04-11T18:00:00
inspireId={versionId=null, namespace=SK.ESKN.CP, localId=873179}
referencePoint=POINT (48.564744882 21.657255808)
endLifespanVersion=null
beginLifespanVersion=null
nationalCadastalZoningReference=873179
upperLevelUnit=null
name={grammaticalGender=null, pronunciation=null, spelling={transliterationScheme=null, text=Stanča, script=null}, sourceOfName=null, grammaticalNumber=null, nameStatus=null, language=null, nativeness=null}
geometry=MULTIPOLYGON (((48.574338585 21.658480965, 48.574338191 21.658512458, 48.574338037 21.660440916, 48.571672503 21.660582986, 48.571620629 21.660801476, 48.571430898 21.660870826, ...21.650799528, 48.573984887 21.650927851, 48.573980203 21.651022416, 48.57389808 21.65107354,21.655316079, 48.574095809 21.656069217, 48.574328243 21.65784314, 48.574342838 21.658128299, 48.574338585 21.658480965)))
id=cpZoningS.1
originalMapScaleDenominator=null
estimatedAccuracy={null=-1.000000, uom=m}
validTo=null

    at org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.parsers.PullParserFeatureReader.parse(PullParserFeatureReader.java:153)
    at org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.parsers.PullParserFeatureReader.parse(PullParserFeatureReader.java:50)
    at org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSFeatureReader.<init>(WFSFeatureReader.java:48)
    at org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(WFSFeatureSource.java:298)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getReader(ContentFeatureSource.java:636)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:174)
    ... 71 more

I tried to analyze how the geotools library resolves xsd schemas because I suspect the issue relates to external schemas and namespace resolving.
Can I add the missing schemas somehow into the WFSDatastore?

I would suspect the issue is the service would not respond without the "NAMESPACES" parameter in the GetFeature calls with value "xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)")".  - you need to get the owner of the service to fix it

Might be worth trying WFS_STRATEGY set to arcgis

I tried that but it doesn't seem any better.

Do you think the server setup is incorrect? Here's the GET request you can access even from web browser:
link
this returns error but when i add the namespace parameter into the same request it works "&NAMESPACES=xmlns(ns,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)"

like this:
https://inspire.skgeodesy.sk/eskn/rest/services/INSPIREWFS/kn_wfs_inspire/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&LANGUAGE=&TYPENAMES=ns%3ACadastralZoning&MAXFEATURES=1&COUNT=1&NAMESPACES=xmlns(ns,http%3a%2f%2finspire%2eec%2eeuropa%2eeu%2fschemas%2fcp%2f4%2e0)&f=image

might be related to the entity resolution code that was added - https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/config.html#external-entities-resolution - I haven't looked but its probably in the GeoTools code base

So this parameter is (or should) only required on GET or KVP requests (see section 6.3 of the standard), so the obvious work around is to switch to POST requests which are XML encoded and should contain the namespaces directly. However, I can only get a timeout with a POST request.
While GeoTools' StrictWFS_2_0_Strategy does set a NAMESPACES value, it only does so if
!XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX.equals(typeName.getPrefix())

It's probably worth opening an enhancement request to relax that test, and add some unit tests for that code using this WFS server. But bear in mind that it's any unsupported module so there's no guarantee that anyone will look at it.
